# Breakpoint will not currently be hit. Unbound Breakpoint

Tags: debugging, blazor-webassembly, breakpoints

I have had this occur periodically.  Once it does, it doesn't seem to go away and I have not been able to figure out why.  It is a productivity killer.

I get the message:  "Breakpoint will not currently be hit.  Unbound Breakpoint."

And the breakpoint does not work.

In trying to research and debug, I have looked at debug/modules.  This is a WebAssembly solution and I have noticed that the modules for both the Shared and Server projects are in modules, but the client is not.  Should it be there?

My breakpoints work when set in the server project.  They also work in the shared project when called from the server project, but not when called from the client.

I have deleted pdb files, cleaned, rebuilt, and re-booted.  Nothing helps.  Breakpoints are sill displaying as "unbound".

Comment: 1.5 years ago I had a similar problem and received feedback on SO that solved it:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70659915/stopped-breaking-at-breakpoints-in-blazor-webassembly-client-app-vs2022/70671083#70671083

This is not helping as the inspectUri is already set.  I do not see any differences in the LaunchSettings from how it looked a few days ago when breakpoints were working.

Comment: An update.  I had recently upgraded my DevExpress Blazor components.  So i restored to prior to that and tested, then re-upgraded and tested again.  My results have changed a bit, not sure how or if this could be related.

Before:  The breakpoints indicated they would not be hit as referenced above.

Now:  That indicator is gone.  Most of the time, the breakpoints will not be hit but occasinally they will.  I have not been able to figure out why.  The code that I have it set on retrieves the data for my form, so I know it is aways executed even if the breakpoint doesn't fire.

Comment: Also.  I am not getting any responses on Stack Overflow.  Does anybody have a suggestion on a forum that might be a better fit for this issue?

Comment: An update:

I found that by deleting the vs, obj, and bin folders I am able to restart breakpoints.

However, I am finding that I need to do this multiple times a day - any suggestions on why or how to fix this?  In some cases I am simply deleting a breakpoint and adding another.

Comment: One more update.  finding that frequently, deleting the vs, bin , and object folders does not correct the issue.  In these cases, so far, they will eventually start working again.  However, they have currently not worked in the last 24 hours despite deleting vs, bin, obj repeatedly, deleting the ms Edge cache, and re-starting both the application and my laptop repeatedly.

Any suggestions including those on another forum are appreciated.

Comment: I case this provides insight.

In the minutes since my last post, I added a breakpoint on the server in a WebApi and re-tested.  That is the only change.

Not only did it work, but the breakpoints in the client that had been failing started working again. 

Sadly, I am expecting that later today the client side breakpoints will again stop working.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are running into the same case I had?.

I can't figure out if you are using Visual Studio or Rider. Sorry beforehand if my case, doesn't match your case. I wondered about the randomness in it quite some time before I figured out what was going on, so hopefully this can help you or someone else as well.

I am using Jetbrains Rider.
I have a Client using C# Blazor and Webassembly.
I have a Rest server written in C#.

Sometimes when I start both the Server and Client up in debug mode my Client breakpoints are not hit. Since they where both started in debug, I would expect all the breakpoints to be hit.

I found out that somehow Rider has selected to hit breakpoints on either the Client or Server, but not both at the same time and that I can switch between what is activated in the Services tool window if I have added .Net Launch Settings Profile.

When I click with the mouse on the Web.Client and give that line focus, the client breakpoints will be hit and when I click on WebApi the server breakpoints will be hit.

When the client breakpoints are deactivated they will have a grey circle that is crossed out and the message  "xxx is not found among the loaded symbol documents".

I attached a screenshot:[image: Switching between what breakpoints should be hit in Jetbrains Rider]

Edit:
Today I discovered another funny thing.
Sometimes the debuggers (tried it with both MS jit debugger and Riders jit debugger) will not break on the breakpoints even though they look good. If I AFTER I start the program delete the breakpoints and readd them, then they work... *sigh*

Comment: Thank you Jesper.  I hadn't checked this in a while, but am still suffering from the same symptoms.  I am using Visual Studio, but will investigate whether there is a parallel.

I appreciate your help as this has been a huge and ongoing time drain.